# Taking my input and comparing it in a while loop, fgets?

Tags: c, loops, comparison, while-loop, fgets

EDIT: I had to add a getchar(); after scanf("%i", &choice); now it asks only once!

Apparently its the case switch that's causing it to output twice. If I call the function outside the case switch it ouputs 1, but if I called it inside the switch it outputs twice

What is causing this? I suspect the scanf choice?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>

        void test();
        void choose();
        int main(void)
        {   
//if i call here its fine
            test();
            choose();
            return 0; 
        }

        void choose()
        {
            int choice;

            do
            {
                printf("1 - Testing if double ask\n");
                printf("2 - Exit\n");
                printf("Please enter your choice: ");       
                scanf("%i", &choice);

                switch(choice)
                {//but pressing 1 here asks twice?
                    case 1:         
                        test();
                        break;
                    default:
                        if(choice !=2)
                            printf("Input Not Recognized!\n");
                        break;          
                }
            }
            while(choice !=2);
            if(choice == 2)
                printf("Ciao!");
        }
        void test()
        {
printf("HELLO");
                char *name = malloc (256);

                do      
                {
                    printf("Would you like to continue (y/n)\n");
                    fgets(name, 256, stdin);
                }
                while(strncmp(name, "n", 1) != 0);
                free (name);
        }
```

Comment: Use single quotes with that one character or `strcmp()` (which will be `0` if they're equal).

Comment: Please print out name after fgets, and add that to the post.

Comment: Weird, how about just printing out the first character, maybe there is a non-printing character in the stream?

Comment: What do you mean by first character? of char* name?

Comment: printf("name[0] = '%c'\n", name[0]);

Comment: @MWB I will add an image of the cmd ouput on imgur link

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is maybe the loop gets executed twice, try putting a print statement before and after the loop, it should be working...

Comment: I created a new c file and project and pasted just this code and a function call, and it works as it should. I dunno why it wouldn't work with my original code, its just a function

Comment: @MWB I've edited my post if you want to look at it again, apparently case switch is causing it to print twice, any thoughts?

Comment: Can you add a print statement before the do while loop in test()?

Comment: I've added it and it prints it before asking me twice

Comment: @MWB I've solved it. scanf and newline... those two just cause problems... adding getchar() after scanf("%i", &choice); magically made it work! now it prints only once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: you can't compare C strings with the comparison operators `!=` and `==`. You'll need to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) for this.

Furthermore I think you'll find a `do { ... } while` loop more useful in this case. You're checking `name` once before the user has had a chance to add any input.

The next thing to be aware of is that `fgets` will retain the newline in your input, so you'll need to address this in your usage of `strcmp`.

Comment: when you say newline, do you mean, when I enter a letter say "a", it will be like printf("a\n")?

Comment: ah, ok, then I will not touch it since I need store line by line in a text file

Answer (score 1):

String comparison does not work like that in C, you would have to use strcmp in string.h.

Alternatively you could just look at the first character in name.

```
while(name[0] != 'n')
```

Comment: I tried while(name[0]!= 'n' and it works, thanks, but it is still asking me twice